# The program expected this account to be already initialized

Tags: anchor, anchor-test

When I do anchor build, the compiler returns this error caused by mint, ownerTokenAccount, and buyerTokenAccount. Here is my code:

```
it("Is initialized!", async () => {
    // 
    let minter = await splToken.createMint(connection, wallet.payer, wallet.publicKey, null, 1)
    const tokenAccount = // create token account
    // minted 1 nft
    const buyer: anchor.web3.Keypair = await createKeypairFromFile(__dirname + "/keypairs/buyer1.json");
    console.log(`Buyer public key: ${buyer.publicKey}`);
    const buyerTokenAddress = await anchor.utils.token.associatedAddress({
      mint: minter,
      owner: buyer.publicKey,
    });
   
    await program.methods.buyNft(
      new anchor.BN(saleAmount)
    )
      .accounts({
        mint: minter,
        ownerTokenAccount: tokenAccount.address,
        ownerAuthority: wallet.publicKey,
        buyerTokenAccount: buyerTokenAddress,
        buyerAuthority: buyer.publicKey,
      })
      .signers([buyer])
      .rpc();
})
```

and this is the code in my contract:

```
pub fn buy_nft(
        ctx: Context<BuyNft>,
        // amount: Option<u64>,
        lamports: Option<u64>,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        system_program::transfer(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                system_program::Transfer {
                    from: ctx.accounts.buyer_authority.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.owner_authority.to_account_info(),
                },
            ),
            lamports.unwrap(),
        )?;
        associated_token::create(CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.owner_token_account.to_account_info(),
            associated_token::Create {
                payer: ctx.accounts.buyer_authority.to_account_info(),
                associated_token: ctx.accounts.buyer_token_account.to_account_info(),
                authority: ctx.accounts.buyer_authority.to_account_info(),
                mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                token_program: ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            },
        ))?;
        token::transfer(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                token::Transfer {
                    from: ctx.accounts.owner_token_account.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.buyer_token_account.to_account_info(),
                    authority: ctx.accounts.owner_authority.to_account_info(),
                },
            ),
            1,
        )?;
        Ok(())
    }
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct BuyNft<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub mint: Account<'info, token::Mint>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub owner_token_account: Account<'info, token::TokenAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub owner_authority: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub buyer_token_account: Account<'info, token::TokenAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub buyer_authority: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, token::Token>,
}
```

In my version, the rent param in associated_token::Create does not exist so I remove it. So can you help me fix this bug? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `buyerTokenAccount` doesn't seem to have been created in your code. The `associatedAddress` function in anchor's utils only derives the address; It doesn't initialize the token account.

Create an ATA for the buyer like this:

```
import * as spl from '@solana/spl-token'

const buyerTokenAccount = await spl.createAssociatedTokenAccount(
    connection,
    buyer
    minter,
    buyer.publicKey
);
```

##### Edit:

Pardon me, I just noticed that the initialization of the buyer's token account is being done on-chain.

In that case, stick to the original way you did it and just derive the account's address instead of actually initializing it in the client.
However in your validator, define `buyer_token_account` like this:

```
#[account(mut)]
buyer_token_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>
```

It's also worth noting that the first argument of the `associated_token::create()` function should be `ctx.accounts.associated_token_program.to_account_info()`, not `ctx.accounts.owner_token_account.to_account_info()`.

Add the associated token program to your Accounts struct:

```
associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
```

Finally, confirm that the user's token account is initialized before it's passed on-chain.

If you still have problems use the `try..catch` construct in your typescript code to view a more comprehensive error log.

If that doesn't help check out the `buy_nft` instruction in this [repo](https://github.com/soltribe/soltribe).

Comment: But it still return buyerTokenAccount cause The program expected this account to be already initialized error

Comment: Edited the answer